# How do I reply to a question?

Tags: gps

I am trying too reply to my question on merging routes/tracks but there is no reply button??

see this dropbox link fo rone of the files:-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7i5afte16zel6n/End%20to%20End%20-%20Day%201%20-%20Lands%20Ends%20to%20St%20Just.gpx?dl=0

Comment: I've edited the link into your original question (edit button at the bottom of the question).

Comment: You scroll down to the box that says "Your Answer" and type.  If what you type might be more of a comment than answer, mention that you don't have enough points to use "add a comment" yet.